# Is it correct to use "too" in "Same to you, too" for emphasis?

Tags: word-choice, too-also

My friend and I had the below conversation on some occasion (let's say the new year).

> F - Happy New Year.
>   Me - Same to you :).
>   F - I wish you have a great year ahead, full of happiness and Success.

To this I reply..

> Me - Thanks a lot. And Same to you, too.

I used "too" here for emphasis. Is the usage of "too" incorrect or redundant here?

Comment: It sounds fine to me, even though I suppose it is a little redundant. I'm pretty sure I've said it exactly that way. On the other hand "I wish you have a great year" is incorrect and should be either "I hope you have a great year" or "I wish you a great year."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F - Happy New Year.

Me - **The same** to you.

F - I **hope** you have a great year ahead, full of happiness and success.

Hope is used to express something that is possible or likely to happen.

I wish you happy birthday. [these are idiomatic and "performative"]

I wish you a happy new year.

[hope versus wish](http://blog.esllibrary.com/2014/06/19/hope-vs-wish/)